# Dropwizard API blocked while jetty Unexpected thread death

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard

My project use Dropwizard to provide REASful API. I found my app do not responsed to the request.

Check my log found this:

```
[2020-01-09 15:42:43.236] WARN   [dw-142] QueuedThreadPool -  Unexpected thread death: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2@3dfd48d5 in InstrumentedQueuedThreadPool[dw]@461905d7{STARTED,8<=25<=1024,i=1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@78ffd10e{s=0/40,p=0}]
[2020-01-09 15:42:47.117] WARN   [dw-145] QueuedThreadPool -  Unexpected thread death: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2@3dfd48d5 in InstrumentedQueuedThreadPool[dw]@461905d7{STARTED,8<=25<=1024,i=2,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@78ffd10e{s=0/40,p=0}]
[2020-01-09 15:42:59.011] WARN   [dw-144] QueuedThreadPool -  Unexpected thread death: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2@3dfd48d5 in InstrumentedQueuedThreadPool[dw]@461905d7{STARTED,8<=25<=1024,i=3,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@78ffd10e{s=0/40,p=0}]
[2020-01-09 15:58:27.903] WARN   [dw-143] QueuedThreadPool -  Unexpected thread death: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2@3dfd48d5 in InstrumentedQueuedThreadPool[dw]@461905d7{STARTED,8<=22<=1024,i=1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@78ffd10e{s=0/40,p=0}]
```

I use `jstack` to print ths JVM info and grep the dw-*

```
cat stack5.log |grep dw-
"dw-542" #542 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd808001000 nid=0x3ba1 waiting on condition [0x00007fd8668ed000]
"dw-141" #141 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd820001000 nid=0x908d runnable [0x00007fd8669ee000]
"dw-140" #140 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd82c001000 nid=0x908c runnable [0x00007fd866aef000]
"dw-139" #139 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd828001000 nid=0x908b runnable [0x00007fd866bf0000]
"dw-138" #138 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd834001000 nid=0x908a runnable [0x00007fd866cf1000]
"dw-137" #137 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd830001000 nid=0x9089 runnable [0x00007fd866df2000]
"dw-136" #136 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd83c001000 nid=0x9088 runnable [0x00007fd866ef2000]
"dw-135" #135 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd838001000 nid=0x9087 runnable [0x00007fd866ff3000]
"dw-134" #134 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd844001000 nid=0x9086 runnable [0x00007fd8670f5000]
"dw-133" #133 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd840001000 nid=0x9085 runnable [0x00007fd8671f6000]
"dw-132" #132 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd84c001000 nid=0x9084 runnable [0x00007fd8672f7000]
"dw-131" #131 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd848001000 nid=0x9083 runnable [0x00007fd8673f8000]
"dw-130" #130 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd884001000 nid=0x9082 runnable [0x00007fd8674f9000]
"dw-117" #117 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fda45236800 nid=0x9033 runnable [0x00007fd8c07dc000]
"dw-116" #116 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fda45234800 nid=0x9032 runnable [0x00007fd8c08dd000]
"dw-115" #115 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fda45232800 nid=0x9031 runnable [0x00007fd8c09de000]
"dw-114" #114 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fda45231000 nid=0x9030 runnable [0x00007fd8c0adf000]
"dw-113" #113 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fda4522f000 nid=0x902f runnable [0x00007fd8c0be0000]
"dw-112" #112 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fda4522d800 nid=0x902e runnable [0x00007fd8c0ce1000]
"dw-111" #111 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fda4522b800 nid=0x902d runnable [0x00007fd8c0de1000]
"dw-110" #110 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fda4522a000 nid=0x902c runnable [0x00007fd8c0ee2000]
```

Any one can help me solve this problem or point out where the error is?

Comment: Dropwizard version is 1.3.9，jetty version is 9.4.14. This problem happens occasionally. I had to restart my app when the problem occurred.

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of Jetty, there's been some improvements in thread death handling since 9.4.14. (last notable change for thread death was in 9.4.19.v20190610)